# Keep initial route active in nested route - React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my routes set up as so:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="elements" component={Elements}>
        <Route path="buttons" component={ElementsButtons}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="design" component={Design}/>
</Route>
```

**HTML**

```
<DropElement to="/elements">Elements</DropElement>
    <ul className="dropElement-list">
        <NavLink to="/elements/tables">Container</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/elements/buttons">Buttons</NavLink>
...
```

**DropElement**

```
export default React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
             router: React.PropTypes.object
     },

     render: function () {
             let isActive = this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, true),
                     className = isActive ? "active dropElement" : "dropElement";

             return (
                     <li className={className}>
                             <Link {...this.props}>
                                     {this.props.children}
                             </Link>
                     </li>
             );
     }
   })
```

**NavLink**

```
export default React.createClass({
     render: function () {
             return (
                 <li>
                     <Link {...this.props}>
                             {this.props.children}
                     </Link>
                    </li>
             );
     }
})
```

This works fine when I access ***/elements***. My question is, how do I keep the active class on 'Elements' whilst I navigate to ***/elements/buttons***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument you are passing to `isActive` is telling the function to only return true if the first argument match the exact path.

So

```
let isActive = this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, true)
```

should be

```
let isActive = this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to)
```

[isActive documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#isactivepathorloc-indexonly)

Comment: Cheers for the explanation as well!